# Como fazer o teste de Dunnett no R?

Tags: r

Supondo que eu realizei o teste ANOVA nos meus dados e deu significativamente diferente, gostaria de realizar o teste de Dunnett justamente para comparar meus tratamentos com o grupo controle. 
Eu devo usar algum pacote específico ou no próprio padrão do R já tem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para fazer o teste de Dunnet, pode usar a função `glht` do pacote `multcomp`.

Como não há dados na pergunta vou usar a base `iris`.

Imediatamente antes de correr o teste deve-se inicializar o gerador de números aleatórios pois, aparentemente, os cálculos da distribuição *t* multivariada chamam o gerador de números aleatórios. Com `set.seed()` or resultados são reprodutíveis.

```
library(multcomp)

data(iris)

fit <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

set.seed(204)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis
summary(glht(fit, linfct = mcp(Species = "Dunnett")))
#
#Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
#
#Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts
#
#
#Fit: aov(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
#
#Linear Hypotheses:
#                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#versicolor - setosa == 0    0.930      0.103   9.033   <1e-10 ***
#virginica - setosa == 0     1.582      0.103  15.366   <1e-10 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

**Nota.**

A ideia de chamar `set.seed` vem das respostas a uma pergunta no Cross Validated, [Porque é que o teste de Dunnett dá valores diferentes de cada vez que corre](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83116/dunnetts-test-in-r-returning-different-values-each-time#83125) em inglês.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Agora uma última dúvida que fiquei. Você colocou 204 no set.seed por algum motivo, ou foi completamente aleatório ?

Comment: @Gus Foi completamente aleatório. Para escolher o valor do `set.seed` eu costumo correr algo como `sample(1e4, 1)`. Ou isso ou `1234` :).